# C# Report multi value Array Parameter display in table

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters, report, rdlc

my first question is:

How can I display all strings in an Array in the Report-Table.
My Report get a multi value parameter (some strings)

```
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource());
        List<ReportParameter> rptParams = new List<ReportParameter>();
        ReportParameter param = new ReportParameter("paramSuchwort");
        param.Values.AddRange(sw.ToArray());
        rptParams.Add(param);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rptParams)
```

The amount of strings in my array is variable. I want to display each string in one table row. The table should grow automatically (add rows)

So how can I do that?

Im using Visual Studio 2005